# Linux - Different threads of a process in different namespaces

Tags: c, linux

I'm looking to open a netlink socket in each existing network namespace to listen for LINK messages associated with interfaces. I'd like to do this from a single process.

According to the `setns()` documentation - "**Given a file descriptor referring to a namespace, reassociate the calling thread with that namespace.**". Can I therefore achieve my task by simply using `pthread_create()` to create a thread for each namespace I require, call `setns()` and then open the netlink socket.

The reason I ask is because I have seen conflicting information regarding `setns()` acting on the process namespace.

Comment: I don't know, but this seems like it would be fairly easy to test.  Create a couple of namespaces, spawn a couple of threads, call `setns()`, and see what you get.

Comment: Can you cite references where you've seen the conflicting information?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** yes, you can ... because you are dealing with network namespaces.

**Long answer:**

Different types of Linux-kernel namespaces sometimes have different constraints and these differences threw you off the track. A really good source is Micheal Kerrisk's man page for [setns(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html). In particular, the section titled "Details for specific namespace types" (deep linking unfortunately not supported).

As for switching a process or thread into a different network namespace, the following applies:

```
Network, IPC, time, and UTS namespaces
    In order to reassociate itself with a new network, IPC,
    time, or UTS namespace, the caller must have the
    CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability both in its own user namespace
    and in the user namespace that owns the target namespace.
```

Please note that network namespaces are "flat", so they do not form any hierarchy.

In contrast, PID namespaces have different constraints, most notably because they do form hierarchies:

```
    Reassociating with a PID namespace is allowed only if the
    target PID namespace is a descendant (child, grandchild,
    etc.)  of, or is the same as, the current PID namespace of
    the caller.
```

And then for something completely different: mount namespaces.

```
    A process can't join a new mount namespace if it is
    sharing filesystem-related attributes (the attributes
    whose sharing is controlled by the clone(2) CLONE_FS flag)
    with another process.
```

This is a slightly convoluted way to say that as soon as you have another thread in your process (=first task), then the mount namespace of any of your threads of this process cannot be changed anymore, neither for the first, nor any other task.